# Edit a js file through shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, sh

I have a requirement to change the contents of a js file config.js the file contains values like:

```
dev:'https://api-beta.com'
content_bucket_name: 'content-beta'
```

I want to change this content using a shell script and save the file. Changed content can look like:

```
dev:'https://api-production.com'
content_bucket_name: 'live-bucket'
```

How can i do this via shell script?

config.js

```
 unifiedTest.constant('CONFIG', {
    env : 'dev',
    api : {
        dev : 'https://api-beta.com', 
    },
    content_bucket_name :"content-beta",
});
```

shell script i have tried

```
#!/bin/bash
file=config.js
content_bucket_name=$1
dev=$2

sed -i -e "s/\(content_bucket_name=\).*/\1$1/" \
-e "s/\(dev=\).*/\1$3/"
```

Comment: Your three examples don't match: dev:'https://api-production.com' is not the same as: dev : 'https://api-beta.com',  which is not the same as: dev=  spaces matter, the : or = matter, which is it actually? Also the , at the end of the line matters, as do the '' wrapping the js. Rewriting text files is easy, but you have to be consistent, and rewrite what is there in reality. Also, you have $2 as the second arg, but $3 in sed, where would that come from? If you fix the consistency issues your problems will go away. No need for \1, just do: "s/dev:.*/dev:$2/" Use the same syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're encountering has to do with the fact that one string has `/` in it, so you get `s/\(dev=\).*/\1https://api-production.com/`, which has too many `/` delimiters. You have a number of choices, but here are the two that make the most sense:

1. Use `awk` (newlines inserted for readability):

   ```
   awk -v name="$1" -v url="$3" '
   /content_bucket_name[[:space:]]*:.*/
   {
       /* Substitute one occurrence of :.* with :"{name}". */
       sub(/:.*/, ":\"" name "\"")
   }
   /dev[[:space:]]*:.*/
   {
       /* Substitute one occurrence of :.* with :"{url}". */
       sub(/:.*/, ":\"" url "\"")
   }
   '
   ```
2. Use a different delimiter for the expression, such as `|` (hopefully the URL doesn't have that delimiter in it; `:`, `/`, '?', ';', `&`, and `#` tend to be bad choices for URL replacements in the general case):

   ```
   sed -i \
       -e "s|\(content_bucket_name[[:space:]]*:\).*|\1'$1'|" \
       -e "s|\(dev[[:space:]]*:\).*|\1'$3'|"
   ```

Note that I altered your substitutions expression to use `:` rather than `=` since that's a requirement for the substitution to effect the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's#dev : .*#dev : '"'https://api-production.com'",'#' config.js
sed -i 's#content_bucket_name:.*#content_bucket_name:''"live-bucket"','#' config.js
```